Why are strong deformations retract more common than their non-strong counterparts?
Category theory strongly emphasizes in that stuff usually only matters up to isomorphism. That makes it seem like the right notion of deformation retract is that of a retract in $hTop$. However it turns out that for most of applications, the stronger condition of strong deformation retract is needed.
I'm wondering if there's some nice explanation of this phenomenon, preferably in categorical terms. Maybe $hTop$ is not a good category to consider, after all?

$\mathrm{hTop}$ is indeed not a very good category to consider, and in particular it does not adequately capture many notions of homotopy theory: For instance, homotopy co/limits are not co/limits in $\mathrm{hTop}$.

I reject the premise that these notions are meaningful to compare. If $i\colon A\rightarrow X$ and $r\colon X\rightarrow A$ are maps, then a retract in $\mathbf{hTop}$ is asking for a homotopy $ri\simeq\mathrm{id}_A$, whereas a strong deformation retract is asking for an equality $ri=\mathrm{id}_A$ and a homotopy $ir\simeq\mathrm{id}_X$ rel $A$. The condition on $ir$ is absolutely crucial in what makes a deformation retract (as opposed to a plain retract in $\mathbf{Top}$) and simply absent in the other perspective. The name "deformation retract" is geometrically motivated, but categorically this is closer to an isomorphism. More precisely, you can consider the coslice category $A\backslash\mathbf{Top}$ whose objects are spaces $A\rightarrow X$ under $A$, morphisms are maps fitting into the obvious commutative triangles and homotopies are homotopies through such maps. Then, a strong deformation retract is nothing but an object of the resulting homotopy category $h(A\backslash\mathbf{Top})$ (which is not to be confused with $A\backslash\mathbf{hTop}$) isomorphic to the initial object $\mathrm{id}_A$.
For the record, the concept of a retract in $\mathbf{hTop}$ exists and has its merits. If $X$ is a retract of $Y$ in $\mathbf{hTop}$, one typically says that $X$ is dominated by $Y$. This is useful due to results such as: if $X$ is dominated by $Y$ and $Y$ has the homotopy type of a CW-compelx, then so does $X$.
Lastly, as a general comment, $\mathbf{hTop}$ is an odd category (from a categorical perspective), but it certainly has its uses. It also has its deficiencies (as @BenSteffan already pointed out, homotopy (co-)limits are not (co-)limits in $\mathbf{hTop}$, which points towards higher categorical formalism for homotopy theory). The moral is this: The language of category theory is absolutely vital in algebraic topology, but at the end of the day, we are still doing topology and not category theory. Thus, the categorical formalism we use is not universal, but depends on the topological scenario that we want to model (the first paragraph illustrates this, I hope).
